# Fancybox 3.0 fade

Tags: fancybox-3

currently i am using fancybox 3.0. It is on autoplay. How do i make it when it changes to next image there will be fade effects ?

This is currently my code

```
 $('[data-fancybox="project1"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true,
                        preload: '40',
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project2"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Different transition effects are available starting from v3.1

Preview - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/LyNXqr

You can get code here - https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/tree/3.1

```
transitionEffect : "fade"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I saw the effects but for fade i cant see much of the effects. The image does not decrease in opacity and the next image appears

Comment: You can make it slower, if you want, but then page content will be visible a bit in the middle of the animation. Therefore it is fading quite fast.

Comment: So how do i insert the effect on my page ? This is my code $('[data-fancybox="project2"]').fancybox({
                            slideShow : {
                            autoStart : true,
                            transitionEffect : "zoom",
                                         },
                            
                                });